# What is value of e^z at infinity in Complex Analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis

My professor told me that in real analysis, e^z  tends to infinity when z tends to infinity but in complex analysis, e^z does not tend to infinity when z tends to infinity. But I'm not understand this difference. Please help me.

Comment: for real analysis, he means "+$\infty$". obviously $e^x \to 0$ as $x \to -\infty$. When someone would say "$e^z$ tends to infinity when $z$ tends to infinity in the complex plane", they'd mean all infinities, including $-\infty$. So, it's not really true in the real line either, if you just say "$\infty$" rather than "$+\infty$"

Comment: This is also discussed in this PDF - https://people.ucsc.edu/~fmonard/Sp17_Math207/lecture8.pdf

Comment: Also, $e^z$ is a periodic function along the imaginary axis. Such a function cannot have a limit in this direction at all.

Comment: I know that e^z is periodic function with period 2πi but how to show that it has no limit on imaginary axis

Comment: As $x \to +\infty$ or $x \to -\infty$, $e^{ix}$ is just going to run around the unit circle forever, so it's not going to approach a limit.

Comment: For any $r\in \Bbb R^+$ we have $\{e^z: z\in \Bbb C\land |z|>r\}=\Bbb C\setminus \{0\}.$

Answer (score 2):

$e^z$ has an *essential singularity* at $z=\infty$, equivalently $e^{1/z}$
has an essential singularity at $z=0$.

If you have a function like $f(z)=z^3+z-1$, its behaviour as $z\to\infty$
is quite straightforward. If $(z_n)$ is a sequence of points with $z_n\to\infty$
(that means that $|z_n|\to\infty$) then $g(z_n)\to\infty$.

But $e^z$ isn't like that. If all we know about the sequence $(z_n)$
is that $z_n\to\infty$, then that tells us little about the sequence $e^{z_n}$.
For instance if $z_n=n$, then $e^{z_n}\to\infty$ in the obvious manner. But
with $z_n=-n$ then $e^{z_n}\to0$. With $z_n=2n\pi i$, then $e^{z_n}\to1$
but with $z_n=ni$ then $e^{z_n}$ wanders around the unit circle but never
converging. One can cook up the $z_n$ to get any limit you like, and also
virtually all sorts of divergent behaviour too.

Comment: How to prove that e^z has an essential singularity at infinity?

Comment: You need to check that its Laurent expansion at $\infty$ has infinitely many nonzero negative coefficients.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Infinity and poles in complex analysis make a lot more sense when you view them from the perspective of manifolds.  I assume the definition of a complex manifold, chart, holomorphic function between manifolds.

If $U$ is an open set in $\mathbb C$, $a \in U$, and $f: U -\{a\} \rightarrow \mathbb C$ is a holomorphic function, then either $f$ either has a removable singularity, a pole, or an essential singularity at $a$.  This depends, respectively, on whether the Laurent series expansion of $$f(z) = \sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb Z} c_n (z-a)^n$$ has no nonzero negative terms, finitely many nonzero negative terms, or infinitely many such terms.

More generally, if $X$ is a complex manifold, $a \in X$, and $f: X - \{a\} \rightarrow \mathbb C$ is holomorphic, it makes sense to talk about whether $f$ has a removable singularity, pole, or essential singularity there.  One takes a chart $(U,\varphi)$ containing $a$, and considers the holomorphic function $f \circ \varphi^{-1}$ in a punctured neighborhood of $\varphi(a)$ in the above sense.  This is independent of chart.

Essential singularities are very strange.  If $f$ has an essential singularity at $a$, then in any punctured neighborhood of $a$, no matter how small, $f(z)$ takes all complex values with at one most exception.  It follows that a sequence of complex numbers $z_n$ can be chosen to approach $a$ such that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f(z_n)$ is any given complex number, with at most one exception.  This is Picard's theorem.

Consider the exponential function $f(z) = e^z$ on $\mathbb C$.  We view $\mathbb C$ as an open submanifold of the Riemann sphere $\hat{\mathbb C} = \mathbb C \cup \{\infty\}$.  Using a chart, we can view $f$ as a holomorphic function on a punctured neighborhood of $\infty$, and ask whether $f$ has a removable singularity, pole, or essential singularity at $\infty$.

We use the chart $(U,\varphi)$ where $U = \hat{\mathbb C} - \{0\}$, and $\varphi: U \rightarrow \mathbb C$ is the homeomorphism given by $\varphi(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ if $z \neq \infty$, and $\varphi(\infty) = 0$.

Then the question of what kind of singularity $e^z$ has at $\infty$, is equivalent to what kind of singularity the holomorphic function $f \circ \varphi^{-1}: \mathbb C -\{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb C$ has at $0$.  For $z \neq 0$, we have

$$f \circ \varphi^{-1}(z) = f(\frac{1}{z}) = e^{\frac{1}{z}} = \sum\limits_{n \leq 0} \frac{z^n}{n!}$$

which is an essential singularity.

Therefore by Picard's theorem, for every complex number $\lambda$ with at most one exception, there exists a sequence of complex numbers $z_n$ tending to infinity such that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} e^{z_n} = \lambda$.